# What is the preffered pattern: Spinning up a connection to database on demand or maintaining a singleton for this purpose?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, webforms, singleton, design-patterns

Moreover if the latter pattern were to be employed on an ASP.NET Website, is using the "always open" connection; thread safe?  or would there be concurrency issues. If there aren't any issues, how would ASP.NET go about implicitly creating I/O threads/ or mutexing to ensure this doesn't happen, or would it?

Questions, questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferred to use the built-in [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx#S4), so spin up the connections as needed.  They will simply come from the pool.

Comment: Is the pool shared amongst worker threads?  Or is there one pool per worker thread, do you know?

Comment: Yes, the pool is shared amongst threads.  I think there's only 1 pool at the machine level, but I could be wrong. Check out Connection Pooling on MSDN to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let ADO.NET manage the connection pool for you.

When you need a new connection instantiate a new one: if one exists in the pool, it will be reset and returned to you. When you dispose a connection it is returned to the pool.